# Greater than and Less than not working correctly with random number in Python

Tags: python, random

I am working on a project that involves random numbers and them being greater or less than another number.

`from random import randint
number = (randint(0, 100))
guess = raw_input("Guess: ")
print number
if (guess > number):
    print str(guess) + " is greater than "+ str(number)`

This code was created to help me debug my problem, but nothing worked.  No matter what I put in as the variable "guess," it would always say that it was larger than the random number.

For example: 
Guess: 0 
27 
0 is greater than 27.

Is this a problem with my code or with the random numbers?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: raw_input() is returning a string.  The ordinal of the character "0" is 48, which is greater than 27.  Python is converting the "0" to the ordinal value 48 in your if statement. You need to convert this to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a `String` type. You need to convert it into an `int`

```
guess = int(raw_input("Guess: "))
```